# Proving $|X^{\mathbb{R}}| \lt |\mathbb{R}^X|$ for $X=\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let $X=\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$.

**Claim:** $|X^{\mathbb{R}}| \lt |\mathbb{R}^X|$

How can this be shown? Note: *We are assuming AC and $A^B$ represents the set of functions from B into A*

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the axiom of choice for this.

**HINT:** First, recall that $|A^B|=|A|^{|B|}$ and that $(X^Y)^Z=X^{YZ}$ in cardinal arithmetic. Now, note that $2^X\leq\Bbb R^X$, but that $|X^\Bbb R|=|X|$.

(This is the same proof as the proof that $\Bbb{|R^N|<|N^R|}$.)

Comment: Thanks, could you explain why we know that $|X^\mathbb{R}|=|X|$?

Comment: That would be a consequence of the first sentence of the hint, along with the fact that $\Bbb R^2$ and $\Bbb R$ have the same cardinality.